# Example of "True Polymorphism"? (Preferably, using Haskell)

Tags: c++, haskell, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I've seen lots of partial definitions of "True Polymorphism", for example [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_Tutorial_for_C_Programmers) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism#Example) but nowhere have I been able to find a clear example of the difference with two concrete examples.

I understand that overloading the `+` operator is some form of polymorphism and that it is implemented differently in Haskell and C++. Can someone show precisely what the difference is with examples in both languages?

Comment: There's no mention of "true polymorphism" in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @delnan You're right, my apologies. I was using that article to help me understand the different types of polymorphism in general

Answer (score 6):

The term you are looking for is "parametric polymorphism", which is different from "ad-hoc polymorphism".

An example of parametric polymorphism is in the type signature for `Nothing`:

```
Nothing :: Maybe a
```

The `a` in the type could be any conceivable type, since `Nothing` inhabits all `Maybe`s.  We say that `a` is parametrically polymorphic because it can be any type.

Now consider this type:

```
Just 1 :: (Num b) => Maybe b
```

This time the `b` cannot be any type: it can only be a type that is an instance of `Num`.  We say that `b` is ad-hoc polymorphic because it can be any member of a set of types, given by the instances of the `Num` class.

So, to recap:

- Parametric polymorphism: Can be any type
- Ad-hoc polymorphism: Constrained by a type-class

Answer (score 3):

There are three types of polymorphism you'll encounter frequently ( with C++ and Haskell examples ).

**Parametric polymorphism** in functional languages is a feature of type systems where the type of a function is an expression quantified over type variables. The input types constrain free parameters in signature which determines the output type. For example the map function takes a function as its first argument which determines the type of the input list and the output list.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

In type theory parlance the signature is often written:

```
 ∀ a. ∀ b. (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

C++ can achieve the effects of parametric polymorphism through templates, but is in my opinion very brittle ( i.e. leads to vague compile errors ) and lacks the formalism found in found functional languages:

```
template <class T>
T add(T a, T b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

**Ad-hoc polymorphism** is when functions with the same name act differently when "viewed" with different type signatures. In Haskell this is expressed with type classes. The type `a` in signature for `(+)` is bounded to types which implement the `Num` type class.

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

class Num a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a

instance Num Int  where
    (+) = plusInt
```

**Subtype polymorphism**. Not present in Haskell but other languages ( Scala, ML ) have subtype polymorphism.  In object oriented languages this is usually a language feature where different object instances implement a method or property calls with the same name and are dispatched depending on the semantics of the object model. In C++ for example:

```
class Animal {
public:
 virtual void speak() = 0;
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
 void speak() { 
    printf("Meow");
 }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
 void speak() { 
    printf("Woof");
 }
};
```

The thing to remember about polymorphism is to separate the core idea from the implementation. For example, ad-hoc polymorphism is not the same as type-classes, it's just one expression of it.

Comment: When you say ML has subtype polymorphism, are you referring to OCaml?

Comment: If you look at the link I provided [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_Tutorial_for_C_Programmers), it seems to say that the `+` operator is an example of "True Polymorphism" in Haskell, where in your answer, you used it to demonstrate Ad-hoc polymorphism. I'm confused

Comment: In the case of that article, it's saying that C doesn't support any type of polymorphism. If you read "true polymorphism" as "any type of polymorphism" it will make more sense.